# Is there way to have function parameters be used to call on dictionary keys?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary with numerical values assigned to elements of the periodic Table.
I'd like to have a function where I can have one of the parameters as one of the elements so that a user can do calculation just with the inputting parameters.

This is what I had so far

```
ele={"H":3, "He":7, "O":9}

def func(x,y,z,d)
    i=ele["x"]*y + ele["z"]*d
    return i
func("H", 2, "O", 3)
print(i)
```

For `i` I'd want to see 33 but it doesn't even get that far.
I keep getting a `KeyError` for `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karim!

When you place any text between quotes it is considered a string, not a variable. Because of that, your code tells python to look for the key "x" in the elements dictionary (in the variable ele). Since there is no x key on it, python raises a KeyError exception.

All you have to do is get rid of the quotes.

`ele={"H":3, "He":7, "O":9}

def func(x,y,z,d)
    i=ele[x]*y + ele[z]*d
    return i

print(func("H", 2, "O", 3))`

Please note that you can't print the content of the variable "i" from outside function "func" since it is a local variable.
Printing function "func" directly will do what you intended to do, as long as that function returns "i".

Comment: Thank You! This helped out a lot. I do have a follow up question, can I have the dictionary name as Parameter of the function. For example `def funct(x,y,z,d,b) ` with `x` being `ele` in the formula `i=x[y]`. Having tried it I get a `TypeError` stating that `string indices must be integers`

Comment: @KarimShawky consider reducing this problem to the one just solved: let "ele" be a key in a dictionary, like this: `data = {"ele": {"H":3, "He":7, "O":9}, "other": {"some": 42, "values": 21}}`

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can use variables as dictionary keys. Your mistake is that you are using a literal `"x"` instead of the variable `x`.

```
In [1]: ele = {"H": 3, "He": 7, "O": 9}

In [2]: def func(x, y, z, d):
   ...:     return ele[x] * y + ele[z] * d
   ...: 

In [3]: func("H", 2, "O", 3)
Out[3]: 33
```